# PHP PDOStatement->execute is very slow

Tags: php, sql, pdo

If I execute some query with phpmyadmin it display the elapsed time 0.0002 sec, that's 0.2 milliseconds. 
If I execute the same query through PHP, using PDO, the elapsed time (just for the third line in the sample code below) is 20 milliseconds.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$cmd = $db->prepare($sql);
$cmd->execute(array($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4));
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: that's normal, PDO does a lot of other stuff inside

Comment: after I analyzed the problem a little bit more carefully I saw that the queries were slightly different; PDO and phpmyadmin perform at the same speed level;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing at all, apart from the fact that you're preparing the statement first, and then executing, which will take up (a bit) more time. That should **not** cause the fact that it's a hundred times as slow though. Try to explain the query (EXPLAIN SELECT), and see what it's doing. I find it hard to believe that using a prepared statement is that much slower.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, PhpMyAdmin is executing a query verbatim. PDO has to prepare the query, parse your parameters, bind them, and *then* execute it. **It's not a fair comparison.**

Second, I 'm not sure if the measurements you are getting are accurate (0.2 msec is awful fast, I wouldn't expect it for *any* query).

Answer (score 1):

If the second query is faster, it's probably the connection time. The connection to the DB is initialized when the first query is sent.